# Can I achieve this with Wordpress?

Tags: images, database, server

Feels nice to be part of StackExchange.

I used to make websites with wordpress around 8 years ago but now I’m a bit out of the loop. Well I was given an offer to make a website with a bit of unusual combination of features. My question is, can I create all these features with the plugins available today. The features are the following:

Create a login system for customers with bank card details ready for payments.
Allow the customers to upload a picture. Give the customers the ability to edit the picture by adding a text label on it. Add the picture to an active group. These pictures in the group should be available to be sent to another small server along with some other text information.
Pay for adding the picture to the group.
Start a new procedure on a different page. Pick date, time, duration and one of the active pictures.Pay for the service.

The date-time and the picture has to be sent to another server.
In the second server the date-time and the new picture path has to be inserted in a database.

This will be used in some kind of regional banner rotation.

Comment: You'd probably need to custom write a plugin or a series of plugins (if you wanted to separate out the functionality) to get something like this.  When you get to intricate and very specific use cases like this, you're going to have a nightmare trying to get a bunch of plugins to work together to get a 'kind of solution'.  I'd also add that downloading and installing plugins isn't WordPress development, but rather 'using WordPress'.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Tony. You saved me a lot of time :) At least now I know that I have to focus on some website coding.